# Comparing datetimes between different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two different data frames.

```
df1= 
index Time
0   2009-09-13 01:17:00
1   2009-09-13 02:17:00
2   2009-09-13 03:17:00
3   2009-09-13 04:17:00
4   2009-09-13 05:17:00
............
```

This is a time-series data with hourly interval spanning in total 10 days.
and

```
df2=
    Report Time                 x
0   2009-09-13 01:17:00         1
1   2009-09-13 02:20:00         27
2   2009-09-13 02:25:00         1
3   2009-09-13 05:33:00         100
..............
```

I want to iterate the "df1" hourly time data through "df2" and do the summation of "x" to its hourly value. Then The hourly data will store the x value.

The output should look like this:

```
index Time                    x
0   2009-09-13 01:17:00       1
1   2009-09-13 02:17:00      28
2   2009-09-13 03:17:00       0
3   2009-09-13 04:17:00       0
4   2009-09-13 05:17:00       100
```

Note that all of the x value should be added together within the same hour for the dataset "df1".

I have tried to implement for loop but couldn't complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DatetimeIndex.floor` to get same time between the 2 dataframes:

```
# Ensure the columns have datetime64 dtype
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Report Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Report Time'])

out = (
    df1.merge(df2.groupby(df2['Report Time'].dt.floor('H')).sum(), 
            left_on=df1['Time'].dt.floor('H'), right_index=True, how='left')
      .fillna(0)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                 Time      x
0 2009-09-13 01:17:00    1.0
1 2009-09-13 02:17:00   28.0
2 2009-09-13 03:17:00    0.0
3 2009-09-13 04:17:00    0.0
4 2009-09-13 05:17:00  100.0
```

Details:

```
>>> df2.groupby(df2['Report Time'].dt.floor('H')).sum()
                       x
Report Time             
2009-09-13 01:00:00    1
2009-09-13 02:00:00   28
2009-09-13 05:00:00  100

>>> df1['Time'].dt.floor('H')
0   2009-09-13 01:00:00
1   2009-09-13 02:00:00
2   2009-09-13 03:00:00
3   2009-09-13 04:00:00
4   2009-09-13 05:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a `merge_asof`:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Report Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Report Time'])

(pd
 .merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on='Report Time', right_on='Time')
 .groupby('Time')
 .agg({'x': 'sum'})
 .reindex(df1['Time'], fill_value=0)
 .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
                 Time    x
0 2009-09-13 01:17:00    1
1 2009-09-13 02:17:00   28
2 2009-09-13 03:17:00    0
3 2009-09-13 04:17:00    0
4 2009-09-13 05:17:00  100
```

Comment: I have a question. To further modify this problem, if I want to have x value to be the summation of "each hour value and its previous hour value", do I need to implement for loop in the final output? or can I do it before the final output.

Comment: Ideally no, with pandas you can use `shift` to get the previous value. The exact code depends on your exact calculation. Probably worth reading the doc of `shift`, giving it a try and asking a new question if you have issues ;)